# SQL: Finding MAX value of attribute 1 from result grouped by attribute2 in VB.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to grouped by attribute 2 [pos] of sqlite database and then get max value of attribute 1 [tagcount].
This works fine in sqlite3 on cygwin.

```
 sqlite> 
     select max(tagcount),pos 
     from (
          select tagcount,pos 
          from sense,synset 
          where sense.synsetid=synset.synsetid 
            and wordid in(
                      select wordid 
                      from word 
                      where lemma="run"
                         )
           ) 
      group by pos 
      order by tagcount DESC;
```

Resulting in the following output

> 106|v
>
> 18|n

But when I copy the exact query in VB.net it gives me the following error

> You tried to execute a Query that does not include specific expression
> 'tagcount' as part of aggregate function

What change should be made in the query so that VB.net does not complaint about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be your order by as it's not an aggregated value and isn't included in your group by.

Comment: Yeah you are right, since tagcount is not included in group by it is throwing an error. But if it is included then I do not get the desired result. Any way to get around it?

Comment: You should remove the order by (it doesn't make sense as it is, you can't order by a set of values) or replace it with max(tagcount) or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I do get the correct rows even if I remove order by - but by default it is ASC and I want DESC. But this partly solves my problem. I will access the resulting rows in the reverse order :P.

Comment: You can use max(tagcount) to order by the values that you are selecting, but tagcount on its own could refer to any of the values for that pos.